# How to remove certain elements of google new tab page permanently

Tags: google-chrome

I do not know anything about computer engineering. I have a good theme on google and it annoys me that the most visited sites blocks my view of it, I want to remove that element of the new tab page, I managed to remove it via inspect element, but it's obviously not permanent, is it possible to remove it permanently and if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Chrome extension "Super Evil New Tab". It lets you edit the HTML of the Chrome "New Tab" page and save your changes, basically using the inspect tool but keeping all your work.

Hope this helps.